# What options exist for viewing mp4 tags in list view?

Tags: nautilus, mp4, tag

I have several mp4 videos. When using Windows7 Explorer I can create a details view (or list view) of the mp4 tag information on these videos, which makes it easy to organize them by genre, title, artist, etc.

Unfortunately, Nautilus can't read mp4 tag data. Nautilus also can't read mp3 tag data. Although not ideal, a way I sometimes use to work around Nautilus' omission is to use Banshee to display the mp3 tags.

What solutions exist (if any) that will allow me to display mp4 tags of my video files when using Ubuntu? I'm looking for a details/list like view of the files like a typical File Browser would provide or maybe a dedicated video player that can give a list view of files like Banshee does with mp3s.

Comment: Nautilus has limited meta data support - right-click a file, properties, audio. Doesn't let you order/filter by them, though.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at EasyTag (available in Software Center).

As shown in the screen-shot - it has mp4 tag capability - shows in list view (scrollable through various columns) and you can sort, ascending and descending.

[image]

(dont have mp4's myself - but the mp3's in the screen-shot should give you an idea of the applications capability)

Answer (score 1):

`nautilus-columns` from `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` works great. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-columns
```

Here are the columns included:

[image: nautilus-columns screen shot]

Comment: Please don't create duplicate answers for very similar questions. Instead flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I answered this question ~2.5 years ago.  I think I had a score of 5 at the time.  I hadn't yet learned all the do's and don't of StackExchange.  I will strive to not transgress like this going forward.  ;-)

Comment: I suspected as much. I just stumbled over the two while looking for a good moderation approach for a late answer to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at KDE's Dolphin file manager. Starting from KDE 4.9, it will do exactly what you are asking for: http://ppenz.blogspot.nl/2012/06/improved-views.html

I suggest you give it a try when KDE 4.9 comes out. Nautilus is quite archaic when it comes to adopting new features.